References on the Sturm–Liouville problem from a functional analysis point of view
I'm looking for a reference that discusses the Sturm–Liouville problem from the point of view of functional analysis. More specifically, I would like a reference that discusses the conditions for the Sturm–Liouville operator to be self-adjoint, especially in situations in which the problem is not regular and some of the coefficients may change signs (but still takes place in a Hilbert space).

You might like https://www.amazon.com/Sturm-Liouville-Theory-Anton-Zettl/dp/0821852671/?encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=feyQ1&content-id=amzn1.sym.f911c8db-3a2b-4b3e-952f-b80fdcee83f4&pf_rd_p=f911c8db-3a2b-4b3e-952f-b80fdcee83f4&pf_rd_r=142-9389099-4636217&pd_rd_wg=5glZs&pd_rd_r=edab7673-ccd6-417d-b6a6-bca8bfdd5af7&ref=aufs_ap_sc_dsk

@DisintegratingByParts I found Zettl amazing, but I couldn't find a discussion about these notions from functional analysis. Maybe I just didn't look in the right places, but it seemed he used "self-adjoint" without paying much attention to the domain of the operator (as one would do in functional analysis, but not necessarily in ODE theory)

Have you looked at John von Neumann's book "Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics"? Here's an amazon link: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=john+von+neumann+books&crid=2D1EFO0GGBZRD&sprefix=john+von+neumann%2Caps%2C127&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_3_16 .

@DisintegratingByParts I haven't, but it makes a lot of sense! I'll check it out! =D

Alves : If you don't find what you want in those books, let me know, and I'll look for a few other references.

I found out that John D. Pryce's Numerical Solutions of Sturm–Liouville Problems has some discussions along the lines I desired. More specifically, Chapter 7 discusses the differences between symmetric and self-adjoint operators in the context of Sturm–Liouville problems.
